# Delete a secret gist created as anonymous

Tags: github, gist

I created a secret gist accidentally without signing in (my session expired at the very right time, I think).. anyway to delete it.. because it has sensitive data.

[image]

Comment: Wait, you created a gist, which was meant to be public but contained code you didn't want to share?

Comment: No, I created it as secret.. which is not letting me to even edit or delete that code.. (maybe there are some settings to do so.. which I dont know)

Comment: Did you check the **edit** page of your secret Gist: a delete link should be there, as mentioned in http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4907307

Comment: @VonC there is no button as **edit** for secret gist..

Comment: Hey @VonC I checked my history page and got to know that my session was expired while creating that code bcos of that it created as `anonymous`.. so this problem started.. Anyway to delete it now? because it has very sensitive code related to company..

Comment: As Paul (should have) commented: a mail to support@github.com is in order.

Comment: yes I did.. waiting for reply..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Update 04/08/2014

Now GitHub has a separate page to handle [deleting of anonymous gists](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-anonymous-gist).

---

Can you email `support@github.com`? They can help you out with this.